# implementation error in gradle scripts - android studio api28

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to implement google services such as ads and also firebase.
I am using the latest version for each implement.

I tried to add //noinspection GradleCompatible, changing versions for some     implemention and added tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory to Manifest

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Help me to fix this error.

```
Error: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory 
value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-76:19 to override.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put these flags in your gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. does you know how to fix this warning too:

WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getMergeResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
Affected Modules: app

Comment: @EladKellner  Use this Def  implementation "com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.5.1"   and check if it works .

Comment: It doesn't. I just saw that i have import errors becuase the change to the properties. He can't resolve import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

Comment: Got it . Just post a new question for this problem .